# Physics forces not affecting dynamic body Scenekit

Tags: ios, game-physics, scenekit

My scene contains;
A static body at the root of the scene

```
_firstNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
_firstNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
_firstNode.geometry = [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:950];
_firstNode.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor greenColor];
_firstNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody staticBody];
 [[scene rootNode] addChildNode:_firstNode];
```

A dynamic body with it's pivot property at (0,-1000,0) with a `SCNAction` that permanently rotates it around the static body.

```
_secondNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
_secondNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);
_secondNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -1200, 0);
_SecondNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody];
_secondNode.geometry = [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:2];
_secondNode runAction:[SCNAction repeatActionForever:[SCNAction rotateByX:-1 y:0 z:0 duration:10.0]]];
[[scene rootNode] addChildNode:_secondNode];
```

When I try apply;

```
[_secondNode.physicsBody applyTorque:SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, 1) impulse:YES];
```

There is no effect on the node as if it was declared as a static body.

Comment: Are you trying to make _secondNode rotate around its own axes?

Comment: The SCNAction is rotating _secondNode about it's X axis and I am trying to use the physics torque impulse to rotate about it's Y axis while the Action continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For physics to simulate the node needs a physicsShape assigned, which is achieved with;

`_secondNode.physicsBody.physicsShape = [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:[SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:2] options:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading what you want correctly, set your second node as so...

```
_secondNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0,-1200,0);
```

This will off set it from the firstNode

Then set its pivot point like so...

```
_secondNode.pivot = _firstNode.pivot;
```

This sets the pivot to the same spot as your firstNode and allows it to rotate around that point. This will only work as long as your firstNode pivot property has not been changed.

Lastly set your action like so...

```
SCNAction rotateByX:M_PI*2 y:0 z:0 duration:10.0
```

Noticed I changed your x setting to M_PI*2 which is equal to 360 degrees. You can use "-M_PI" to rotate the opposite way.

Comment: By adding a physicsShape the impulse is now affecting the node. However this has some how thrown off the pivot and has me lost as to why. The node is now defaulting to (0,1200,0) with the code above.

Comment: I revised my answer above. Let me know if that works!

Comment: This results in _secondNode rotating on the spot as _firstNode.pivot would just pass (0,0,0). I've opened the new question that you've commented on because the issue is now how the two bodies are interacting than physics not working.